# Generate a random number given a range with the rdrand instruction

Tags: casting, x86, x86-64, sse, mov

Here is my goal: I want to generate a random number in x86_64 assembly given a start and a stop. Here is my idea for doing this in pseudo-Python:

```py
def rand_bounded(start, stop):
    return (start / stop) * rand32()
```

By doing `rdrand eax` I can get a random 32-bit number in the `eax` register. Then, I can move `start` into `xmm0` and divide `xmm0` with the second argument on the stack. That should get me `start / stop`. I should then be able to multiply the random 32-bit number with that; let's call that `A`. `cvtss2si` seems like the right instruction to round A to the nearest whole number, based on its [description](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtss2si) here.

My problem arises when actually trying to write this. Each time that I run my code (Clang, macOS) I get an exit code of zero, which means that the result isn't calculated correctly (I'm moving the result into where the exit code goes, `rdi`, below). My guess is that it has to do with mixing 64-bit and 32-bit numbers somewhere, but other than that I have no clue what is causing this to fail. Does anyone knowledgeable on x86_64 assembly know what I am doing wrong?

```
    .global _main
    .data

float_storage:
    .int 0

    .text

rand_bounded:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    movss xmm0, [rbp + 16]
    divss xmm0, [rbp + 24]  # xmm0 = start / stop

    rdrand eax
    mov [float_storage + rip], eax  # float_storage = rand()

    movss xmm1, [float_storage + rip]
    mulss xmm0, xmm1  # xmm0 *= float_storage
    cvtss2si eax, xmm0  # use movd?

    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret

_main:
    push 10  # stop
    push 5  # start
    call rand_bounded
    add rsp, 8

    mov rdi, rax
    mov rax, 0x2000001
    syscall
```

Comment: `push 10` and `push 5` push integer values on the stack but then you treat those as single precision floats. As well the exit syscall will only return a value between 0 and 255.

Comment: @MichaelPetch For your first point, how would I convert the stack integer values to single-precision floats? For your second point, I am okay with the exit syscall doing that since my expected random number is only between 5 and 10.

Comment: Just an observation. How does (start/stop)*random32bitnumber give a value between start and stop?

Comment: There is an online converter here: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html . Put a value in the `You entered` field and then hit tab key and it should give you a hex representation that you can use in GNU assembler.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I just noticed that my formula doesn't work. I'll revise it and update the question.

Comment: I am curious. Are start and stop integer values and are the values being returned integers or are you actually looking to return a floating point number between 2 floating point numbers? If this is all integers then there is no need for floats here. You could use the integer `div` instruction which will return a remainder (modulo) . To get an integer number in a range of 2 integer numbers (start and stop) you could do `start+(rand32 mod (stop-start))`. There will of course be modulo bias but that is another issue.

Comment: If you need to include the end value in the range then it would be `start+(rand32 mod (stop-start+1))`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Start and stop are integer values, and I am aiming to return an integer. I'll give your formula a spin.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you, your method worked!